# Como executar uma subconsulta no LINQ C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Como executar uma subconsulta no LINQ C#?

```
SELECT ap.ID
    FROM Aplicativo AP
WHERE AP.Tipo IN (2,6) 
AND AP.ID NOT IN (SELECT filhoID FROM relacoesobjeto WHERE filhoclasse = 555)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria algo semelhante a isso, ajudaria se você tivesse os objetos, variaveis ou parte do seu código pra contextualizar melhor no seu cenário.

```
// SELECT filhoID FROM relacoesobjeto WHERE filhoclasse = 555
var listaIds = db.relacoesobjeto.Where(u => u.filhoclasse == 555).ToList();

// Subquery
// SELECT ap.ID FROM Aplicativo AP WHERE AP.Tipo IN (2,6)
var aplicativo = db.Aplicativo
                    .Where(u => u.Tipo == 2 || u.Tipo == 6)
                    .Where(u => !listaIds.Any(p => p.filhoID == u.ID))
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Obrigado Diego Vieura.. Isso mesmo que queria! Funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: @BrunoSouza Que bom que eu ajudei! :)

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer é criando uma nova variável com o `let` onde ficariam seus ids, em seguida basta usar o método `Contains` para verificar se o `id` corresponde na consulta.

Veja esse exemplo:

```
var apps = from a in Aplicativo 
            let ids = from r in relacoesobjeto select r.filhoID 
            where ids.Contains(a.ID)
        select a;
```

Veja mais [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25372723/5429980).

Comment: downvoter há algo que eu possa melhorar na resposta?